# Language Introspection for the D language

Tags: d

Is there something like lint for the D language or is there any framework to quickly build a checker?

**Edit 1**

In retrospect i remember that i took a look a week ago at the tool DScanner. The tool can only return the Classnames and some other stuff but it includes a full Lexer and Parser.

Sourcecode https://github.com/Hackerpilot/Dscanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something like lint for the D language

[Stefan Rohe will be presenting AnalyzeD at this year's D conference](http://dconf.org/talks/rohe.html). However, [the AnalyzeD website](http://analyzed.no-ip.org/) seems to be currently down.

> or is there any framework to quickly build a checker?

[Brian Schott is working on std.d.lexer](http://forum.dlang.org/post/dpdgcycrgfspcxenzrjf@forum.dlang.org), a proposed inclusion for Phobos (D's standard library), which would allow lexing D programs.

Some other projects can be found on the D Wiki:

http://wiki.dlang.org/Lexers_Parsers

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the already-mentioned `std.lexer`, there is a very nice project called Pegged.

[Pegged](https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged)  is a parsing expression grammar (PEG) generator by Philippe Sigaud. Parses at runtime and compile-time. There is a nice [tutorial](https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged/wiki/Pegged-Tutorial) that explains how to use it.